# Nuget Restore - The remote name could not be resolved

Tags: visual-studio, nuget-package-restore

I am having a problem with Nuget Restore (occurs in VS 2015/2017 and using nuget on command line).  I get the following error:

```
Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
  The remote name could not be resolved: 'locahost'
```

I guess the issue is with the apparent typo in '`locahost`', but I'm not sure where this value is coming from?

My Nuget config in %AppData%/Roaming/Nuget looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageRestore>
    <add key="enabled" value="True" />
    <add key="automatic" value="True" />
  </packageRestore>
  <packageSources>
    <clear />
    <add key="NuGet" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
  <disabledPackageSources />
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="NuGet" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
  </activePackageSource>
</configuration>
```

Where else could this be coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by configuring nuget to use a proxy:

```
nuget.exe config -set http_proxy=<proxy-url>:<port>
```